# How to make GitKraken show topological order (rather than date order)...?

Tags: git, gitkraken

GitKraken shows git trees using date order.

Is there a way to make GitKraken use topological order...?

I've looked at GitKraken's options/settings and I couldn't find anything that specified topo vs date, and I couldn't find anything addressing this online.

Comment: Send them an email and let us know, they are pretty responsive.

Comment: ok, done

(...having an *individual* license, I suppose I won't get a direct response from them...)

Comment: Any news on this topic?